# renaming object keys in php

Tags: php, object, key

I have spent the whole day since morning to handle this without the solution.

I have these data comes from database. I use PHP PDO connection.

```
Array (
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [testing_id] => 4 [testing_name] => please [testing_location] => kjnkdsnkdnskjndkjsndjknskdnsk )
 [1] => stdClass Object ( [testing_id] => 3 [testing_name] => please [testing_location] => jknds ndns )
 [2] => stdClass Object ( [testing_id] => 2 [testing_name] => please [testing_location] => be done to me ) )
```

I want to rename keys in objects instead of testing_id to be just id, testing_name to be name etc.

I have write number of functions like this below

```
function remove_keys($arr, $table) {
  $object = new stdClass();
  foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    $x = (array) $val;
    foreach ($x as $key2 => $value) {
      $new_key = str_replace($table, '', $key2);
      $object->$new_key = $value;
    }
  }
  return $object;
}
```

and this

```
function replaceKey(&$array,$table) {    
  $x = array();
  foreach($array as $k => $v){           
    $new_key = str_replace($table, '', $k);
    array_push($x, $new_key);
  } 
  $array = array_combine($x, $array);
  return $array;
}
```

In all cases, I get only one object result instead of renaming the whole object

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [name] => please [location] => be done to me )
```

How can I rename each index in object and get the full object renamed? Any help please

I need the output to be like this

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [name] => please [location] => kjnkdsnkdnskjndkjsndjknskdnsk )
  [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [name] => please [location] => jknds ndns ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [name] => please [location] => be done to me ) )
```

I have searched here without any similar solution

Comment: PDO supports selecting data into your own class. You should create your class with correct field names (eg. `id`,`name`,`location`) and use `$statement>setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'your_class');`. See [This](http://coderlearner.com/PHP_MySQL_PDO_Fetch_CLASS) for a complete example.

Comment: If changing to FETCH_CLASS is not an option (for whatever reason) you can also change your query to rename fields, for example `SELECT testing_id as id,testing_name as name,testing_location as location FROM testing_table WHERE [...];`

Comment: Thanks, but can't I handle it in php codes. I have a database with more than 30 tables, create class for each one will be a great pain

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the object value in the foreach:

```
$object->$new_key = $value;
```

`$object` is always the same variable, try something like this:

```
function remove_keys($arr, $table) {
  $temp_array = array();
  foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    $object = new stdClass();
    $x = (array) $val;
    foreach ($x as $key2 => $value) {
      $new_key = str_replace($table, '', $key2);
      $object->$new_key = $value;
    }
    $temp_array[] = $object;
  }
  return $temp_array;
}
```

This will give you back an array of objects.

Comment: Greeeeet, thanks Ende Neu, It just work fine.... I can't believe if it was just a trick like that...Thanks sana